# How can I create a trainingsset for SVM (EmguCV)?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I´ve got several problems with my task. I want to implement an emotion recognizer. After my long search for methods, I think a combination of a feature extractor like SURF or PCA combined with SVM could be a good idea. I´ve implemented a detector for relevant parts of the face like mouth and eyes. And now I want to extract the features and store them as matrix.

I know I have to create a training set and a test set of my collected images and preprare the training set for SVM. And that´s my problem.

Which extractor will be the best? And does every extractor give a vector back with features?

I don´t know how to start:-( How I get the features as a vector and save them as a matrix....

Sorry, I don´t have enough experiences in machine learning. I´m searching for many days to find the answer and I hope someone can give me advice.....thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is complicated, you should first focus on how SURF work, then how SVM work, and also have a look to Bag of Visual words.

First try to use SURF. Most of "extractor" (SIFT, SURF, etc.) work in two time 1)detection - detecting interesting points 2)extraction - extract features. The problem is that you can't use SURF directly in SVM because one image have several points which have 64 or 128 features. The problem is that the number of points in each image can be different, and SVM need the same number of feature for each image. So you should have a look to [Bag of Visual Words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision).

[SURF- Emgu tutorial](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/SURF_feature_detector_in_CSharp)

[SVM - Emgu tutorial](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/SVM_%28Support_Vector_Machine%29_in_CSharp)

Comment: OKay, I´ve read a lot about SURF, but I´ve got one thing which I don´t understand. I´ve got a database with facial expression for every emotion. What will be better: sort every emotion into a folder and extract from them the feature vectors? And then use BoW to train on it?

Comment: Yes, you can try this. 
I know it will work for recognizing "objects" but I don't know for recognizing emotions...

Comment: okay, when I´ve got 6 matrices (one for every basic emotion), then I put them together into a big matrix for using BoW? Or did I unterstand it wrong?

Comment: Yes you have to do this. I will work better with several examples for each class. After you have to apply k-means in order to create the "codebook".

Comment: My big problem is that I don´t know how to loop through my folder and extract.....

Comment: Okay, I tried to implement using OpenSURF, but it doesn´t run.

it would be enough for my work if I can get a 1 vs. all SVM. I think my code is to complicated.....but I´m not sure.

I´ll show you my code in a seperate answer....